# Contacts not visible on icloud.com

Tags: ios, icloud, contacts

I have an iPhone SE with iOS 12.4.1

I just visited www.icloud.com and noticed that the majority of my contacts are not there. I have about 800 contacts on my phone, while on the iCloud website under "Contacts" only about 50 are visible (half of them Skype contacts, I'm am missing the phone contacts. Entries with name and phone number.)

I tried the most tricks suggested on the web:

- reboot phone
- turn Contacts sync on and off on phone
- logout phone from apple ID , reboot, then sign back in

Nothing helps.

Help!

*Edit:* Mystery (partly) solved. Those contacts were all under the Gmail group. So the new question is: how to back them up to iCloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One recommended approach would be to export all the contacts from Gmail (Google) and import them into iCloud.

Login to your Gmail (Google) account, go to contacts and export all the contacts. You'll find the command in the left sidebar.

[image]

Now login to your iCloud account, go to Contacts, click on the gear in the bottom left and click on import.

[image]

Comment: Looks great! If the contacts will be in both accounts, will they not appear twice on the phone?